# Locus on a parabola

Tags: conic-sections, locus

How could I find the locus of M as P moves of the parabola. P is.(2at, at^2) . M is the midpoint of the x and y intercepts of the normal through P.

So far I was able to find the quation of the normal and thus was able to fund the midpoint.  However I don't really i don't really understand how to find the locus. By the way I have a lot of trouble with my locus so if possible can you please give me up for links or instructions on how to find a locus, in general.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

equation is $x^2=4ay$ for $(2at,at^2)$

slope of tangent
$$2x=4ay'$$
$$y'=t$$
slope of normal 
$$-1/t$$
eqn of normal 
$$y-at^2=-1/t(x-2at)$$
$$ty+x=2at+at^3$$
when $x=0$
$$y=2a+at^2$$
when $y=0$
$$x=2at+at^3$$
M is at $(h,k)\equiv(\frac12(2at+at^3),\frac12(2a+at^2))$

now $h/k=t$
substitute:
$$2k=2a+ah^2/k^2$$
$$2k^3=2ak^2+ah^2$$